# How can I pass an image from my UITableView to my detail UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uitableview

I'm trying to pass an image shown in my UITableView over to my detail UITableView. The images in my tableview are being pulled from a JSON end point. Any idea how I can go about this? At the moment, this is the line crashing my app:

**featureImage.image = [[articleDetail objectForKey:@"Image"] objectForKey:@"filename"];**

Any idea how I can do this properly? See code below.

**TableViewController.m**

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    FullArticleViewController *detailViewController = [[FullArticleViewController alloc]
                                                        initWithNibName:@"FullArticleViewController" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController.title = [[Doctors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"node_title"];
    detailViewController.articleDetail = [Doctors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [detailViewController.featureImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cellImageLink]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

}
```

**DetailViewController.h**

```
{

    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
    IBOutlet UILabel *firstnameLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *descriptionLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *bodyLabel;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *featureImage;

}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *articleDetail;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *featureImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *cellImageLink;
```

**DetailViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 5000)];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.



firstnameLabel.text = [articleDetail objectForKey:@"node_title"];
descriptionLabel.text = [articleDetail objectForKey:@"Opening Paragraph"];
bodyLabel.text = [articleDetail objectForKey:@"Body"];
featureImage.image = [articleDetail sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cellImageLink]];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using something like SDWebImage then you can just call the same code you have above:

```
[detailViewController.featureImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:secondLink]];
```

If the image has been downloaded it will pull it from the cache, if not it will download it.

Comment: I'm totally using SDWebImage! So do I paste this line of code into my TableViewController.m during the segue? Or into the DetailViewController where my crash line is?

Comment: Personally I would pass a doctor object to your details view controller and then I would run that on viewDidLoad. You can run setImageWithURL any time you would call setImage.

Comment: Hey Patrick! See updated code above. Everything seems like it's in order, except in my DetailViewController (on the featureImage.image line), xCode throws me the error "No visible interface for 'NSDictionary' declares the selector 'sd_setImageWithURL'. Which doesn't seem to make much sense, since I've imported the appropriate SDWebImage header file. Any thoughts?